# Documents to prove sufficient means of subsistence when applying for Schengen visas for my family

Tags: visas, schengen, paperwork, proof-of-funds

I will be traveling to the Netherlands with my wife and daughter, and will be supporting all the expenses for my family.

I am applying for the Schengen visa for tourism purpose and intending to submit my bank statements for my wife and daughter as well. Do I need to submit any declaration as well saying that I will be bearing all cost for my family?

Just to add, I will be submitting my marriage certificate with my wife's application and my daughter's birth certificate for my daughter's application. would that be enough for showing that I will bear all the expenses?

Comment: What is it that you're submitting them for?

Comment: @Karlson Sorry, I didn't mention it in the question. It is for the Schengen visa application. I have ammended the question as well.

Comment: The question @Karlson asked is more : what kind of visa? Tourism, Work & Holiday, residence, ...?

Comment: @Vince Work holiday visas or residence permits are not strictly speaking Schengen visas but national visas.

Comment: sorry, I am looking info for Schengen visa from tourism purpose.

Comment: Wouldn't the baby's passport be enough, why birth certificate? Embassy probably won't ask for that. Also, I never submitted the marriage certificate for the Visas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the following reply from the consulate.

> Your wife has her own bank statements, we would like to see them. If not, she can apply with your information, which you will then have to bring threefold; once for yourself, one copy for your wife and one for your daughter.