# Schengen visa for housewife

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, europe, spouses

How difficult or complicated it is to get a Schengen tourist visa for a housewife / homemaker? My wife and I (Indian passport holders) are travelling to Germany for 10 days. Wife is unemployed. Is it possible to get visa only on my bank statement? Is it possible that we can present both our bank statements against my wife's application? Any specific points to remember while collecting the documents/writing the cover letter?

Comment: It depends entirely on the housewife's circumstances.  Unless you can specify them, this question is too broad.

Comment: The key thing is that **your** income must be enough to afford the trip for both of you. The Schengen visa officials try to admit genuine tourists with a low risk of overstay, that means a stable job with steady income higher than the monthly expenditures, so there are savings.But it is entirely normal when only one of member of a married couple is working, and the other one looks after the household. They would see relatively little risk that your wife would overstay and work in Europe while you return home to your job.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Documents to prove sufficient means of subsistence when applying for Schengen visas for my family](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24076/documents-to-prove-sufficient-means-of-subsistence-when-applying-for-schengen-vi) ?

Comment: @Giorgio, done.

Answer (score 2):

The Schengen visa officials try to admit genuine tourists with a low risk of overstay, that means a stable job with steady income higher than the monthly expenditures, so there are savings. The key thing is that your income must be enough to afford the trip for both of you.

But it is entirely normal when only one of member of a married couple is working, and the other one looks after the household. They would see relatively little risk that your wife would overstay and work in Europe while you return home to your job.